# KeyError when using DictReader()

Tags: python, csv

I have a series of .src files that I am trying to input into a dictionary using DictReader(). 
The files look like the following (just the header and the first row):

```
SRC V2.0.. ........Time Id Event T Conf .Northing ..Easting ...Depth Velocity .NN_Err .EE_Err .DD_Err .NE_Err .ND_Err .ED_Err Ns Nu uSt ....uMag Nt tSt ....tMag .MomMag SeiMoment ...Energy ...Es/Ep .SourceRo AspRadius .StaticSD AppStress DyStressD MaxDispla PeakVelPa PeakAccPa PSt
07-30-2010 07:43:56.543 ND     0 e 0.00    152.54    746.45  1686.31     6000   11.76   11.76   11.76    0.00    0.00    0.00 30  0 num    -9.90 30 utm    -3.21   -1.12 2.06e+007 2.22e+000 20.93    6.08e+000 0.00e+000 3.83e+004 1.49e+003 0.00e+000 1.52e-005 1.50e-003 0.00e+000   1
```

Anyways, the following is my code:

```
import csv

Time = {}
Northing = {}
source_file = open(NNSRC, 'rb')
for line in csv.DictReader(source_file, delimiter = '\t'):
    Time = line['........Time'].strip()
    Northing = line['.Northing'].strip()

print Time, Northing
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\xy\NNFindStages.py", line 101, in <module>
    Time = line['........Time'].strip()
KeyError: '........Time'
```

How can I account for the strange way the header is formatted in the file without changing the file itself?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can see what the CSV module made of your format by printing `line.keys()`.

Comment: Alright, I just tried that and it looks like it took the header as the list of keys, which is right. (Unless it took it all as one key). How can I tell the difference?

Comment: `len(line)` will tell you how many items there are in the line. If it is 1, then you didn't use tabs in the header line.

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate. The length is 1. Is there a way to detect what the delimiter is? Apparently it isn't a space, tab, nor a comma (even though it is a .csv file).

Comment: Your *header* is using spaces, the rest of your file is probably stills using tabs.

Comment: Ah, I see. It is working to some extent now. It seems that the headers are offset from the first row by one column though. (Time is reading the third column instead of the second). Do you have any insight?

Comment: The first value on the line seems to be a version string, just remove that from your `headers` before creating the `DictReader`. My answer deals with the header better now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your header line is not using tabs.

When I recreate your data without tabs, the line returned by the `csv` module contains just one (*long*) key. If I recreate it with actual tabs, then I get:

```
>>> source_file = open('out.csv', 'rb')
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(source_file, delimiter = '\t')
>>> line = reader.next()
>>> len(line)
37
>>> line.keys()
['Id', '..Easting', '.NE_Err', 'uSt', 'SeiMoment', 'MaxDispla', 'tSt', 'Ns', 'Nt', 'Nu', '.Northing', '.DD_Err', '...Energy', '....uMag', 'V2.0..', 'DyStressD', 'SRC', 'PeakAccPa', '.SourceRo', '........Time', '.EE_Err', 'T', 'Velocity', 'PeakVelPa', 'AspRadius', '...Depth', 'PSt', '....tMag', '.MomMag', 'AppStress', '...Es/Ep', '.ED_Err', 'Event', '.ND_Err', 'Conf', '.StaticSD', '.NN_Err']
>>> line['........Time']
'ND'
>>> line['.Northing']
'746.45'
```

Note that the values do not need stripping; the module takes care of extraneous whitespace for you.

You can read your header separately, clean that up, then deal with the rest of your data with the `csv` module:

```
source_file = open(NNSRC, 'rb')
header = source_file.readline()
source_file.seek(len(header))  # reset read buffer

headers = [h.strip('.') for h in header.split()]
headers = ['Date'] + headers[2:]  # Replace ['SRC', 'V2.0'] with a Date field instead
for line in csv.DictReader(source_file, fieldnames=headers, delimiter = '\t'):
    # process line
```

The above code reads the header line separately, splits it and removes the extra `.` periods for you to make for more workable column keys, then sets the file up for the `DictReader` by resetting the readline buffer (a side-effect of the `.seek()` call).